# Не получается вызвать onRecieve() с помощью PendingIntent с помощью AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver, pendingintent

В тестовом приложении пытаюсь вызвать метод onRecieve(),действую согласно обучающим примерам,сверял правильность действий несколько раз на разных сайтах,но вызов все равно не происходит.
Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Created","Created");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Log.d("Created","Created2");
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 4000, pIntent);
    Log.d("Created","Created3");
 }
}
```

Код Receiver'a:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("yAAA","Sucess!");
 }
}
```

Comment: Какая версия андроида? Как регистрируете receiver?

Comment: Я его не регистрировал,сейчас зарегистрировал,все заработало,спасибо